# How to get value by column name in php spreadsheet-parser library?

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I'm using [akeneo-labs spreadsheet-parser](https://github.com/akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser) library to extract data from xlsx file.

```
use Akeneo\Component\SpreadsheetParser\SpreadsheetParser;

$workbook = SpreadsheetParser::open('myfile.xlsx');

$myWorksheetIndex = $workbook->getWorksheetIndex('myworksheet');

foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {
    var_dump($rowIndex, $values);
}
```

Actually, you can get value by column index in a loop, is it possible to get value by column name instead?

Comment: Try [phpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) its the bee's neez

Comment: phpexcel very slow !

Comment: Use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), the successor of PHPExcel instead.

Comment: phpExcel is deprecated since 2017 and permanently archived since 2019. Avoid using it

Answer (score 0):

maybe using another package as suggested fixes your problem.
also you can use `array_column` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that in a spreadsheet CSV file by using PHP default function fgetcsv(), you can go throw an overview from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv
fgetcsv — Gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV fields

First of all, save as your Xls file in CSV type then you can take your value from that CSV file by column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
use Akeneo\Component\SpreadsheetParser\SpreadsheetParser;

$workbook = SpreadsheetParser::open('myfile.xlsx');

$myWorksheetIndex = $workbook->getWorksheetIndex('myworksheet');
// all columns
$columns = [];

foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {
    if ($rowIndex == 1) {
        $columns = $values;
    } else {
        $datum = array_combine($columns, $values);
        // get value by column name
        var_dump($datum['name']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with XLSXReader lib.

Simply include and use below code.

```
require('./XLSXReader.php');
$xlsx = new XLSXReader($targetPath);
$sheetNames = $xlsx->getSheetNames();
foreach($sheetNames as $sheetName) {
    $sheet = $xlsx->getSheet($sheetName);
    foreach($sheet->getData() as $row) {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser library doesn't directly provide a method to get values by column name. However, you can achieve this by creating a mapping between column names and their corresponding indices. You can then use this mapping to access values in the row.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
use Akeneo\Component\SpreadsheetParser\SpreadsheetParser;

$workbook = SpreadsheetParser::open('myfile.xlsx');
$myWorksheetIndex = $workbook->getWorksheetIndex('myworksheet');

// Define your column name to index mapping
$columnNameToIndex = [
    'column1' => 0,
    'column2' => 1,
    // Add more columns as needed
];

foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {
    // Access values by column name
    $column1Value = $values[$columnNameToIndex['column1']];
    $column2Value = $values[$columnNameToIndex['column2']];

    // Use the values as needed
    var_dump($rowIndex, $column1Value, $column2Value);
}
```

In this example, replace 'column1', 'column2', etc., with the actual column names from your spreadsheet, and adjust the $columnNameToIndex array accordingly.

This way, you can easily retrieve values by column name within your loop.